# Time conversion does not work in gnuplot

Tags: linux, bash, gnuplot

I have the following snippet to have a graph output via gnuplot.

```
set datafile separator ","

set title "Memory"
set xlabel "Values"
set ylabel "Date"
set ydata time
set timefmt "%H"
set format y "%d/%m/%Y"
set key left top
set grid

plot 'memory-memory-buffered_combined' using 0:2 titl "1" with lines,\
     'memory-memory-cached_combined' using 0:2 title "2" with lines
cat 
pause -1
```

However, when I have the result it starts from 1970.

The first 5 lines of the csv I am reading;

```
epoch,value
1478193413.596,72910
1478193473.412,134432
1478193413.158,65449
1478193411.929,60157
```

So, it is actually November 2016.

Which part of my script should be different?

Comment: When you `plot .. using 0:2` then the line number in your input file will be used for the x axis, and the data in the second column ("value") for the y axis. But from your label commands it seems that you want the "values" on the x axis, and the "date" (presumably column 1) on the y axis. Perhaps you should use `plot .. using 2:1` instead? Also, you might want to set `timefmt` to `%s` if you want to use epoch (see `help timefmt`).

Answer (score 0):

```
set datafile separator ","

set title "irq"
set xlabel "Date"
set ylabel "Values"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%s"
set format x "%d/%m/%Y"
set key right top
set grid

set terminal jpeg size 3600,2100 enhanced font helvetica 20
set output "irq.jpg"


plot "/irq/irq-16_combined" using 1:2 title "irq-16" with lines
```

I applied some changes on the script, however it is still inconsistent. Out of 100 scripts which have same pattern and similar files with same column names and values, only one still have output where time starts from 1970. Have any of you experienced such issue?

Comment: I think it happens when it is overloaded with 10k lines of data. When I prune it, it gets back to desired time interval.

Comment: That would be surprising. I would guess that your data file contains at least one line with a very low value of epoch, which is then converted to the 1970s. What is the output of `stats "filename" using 1` (where filename is the name of your data file)?